# Handle the NoSuchElementException in Fluent Wait

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, nosuchelementexception, fluentwait

I know that in terms of waiting for web element that isn't in the `DOM` yet, the most efficient is a fluent wait. So my question is:

**Is there a way to handle and catch the `NoSuchElementException` or any exception that fluent wait might throw because the element is not existing?**

I need to have a boolean method wherein it will give me result whether the element is found or not.

This method is quite popular on the web.

```
public void waitForElement(WebDriver driver, final By locator){
    Wait<WebDriver> wait = new FluentWait<WebDriver>(driver)
            .withTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .pollingEvery(2, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .ignoring(NoSuchElementException.class);

   wait.until(new Function<WebDriver, WebElement>() {
        public WebElement apply(WebDriver driver) {
            return driver.findElement(locator);
        }
    });
}
```

What I need is, `**.ignoring(NoSuchElementException.class);**` will not be ignored. And once the exception is caught, it will return FALSE. On the other hand, when an element is found, it will return TRUE.

Comment: By asking to ignore `.ignoring(NoSuchElementException.class);` you are breaking the basic logic of `FluentWait`. I think what would suit you is `WebDriverWait`

Comment: Can I use WebDriver wait with polling?

Comment: Definately, you can

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As an alternative as you have wanted to see the implementation of [WebDriverWait](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/WebDriverWait.html) with polling, here are the constructor details :

- `WebDriverWait(WebDriver driver, long timeOutInSeconds)`: Wait will ignore instances of NotFoundException that are encountered (thrown) by default in the 'until' condition, and immediately propagate all others.

  ```
  WebDriverWait wait1 = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
  ```
- `WebDriverWait(WebDriver driver, long timeOutInSeconds, long sleepInMillis)`: Wait will ignore instances of NotFoundException that are encountered (thrown) by default in the 'until' condition, and immediately propagate all others.

  ```
  WebDriverWait wait2 = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10, 500);
  ```

---

### Update :

To answer to your comment, you need to define the *WebDriverWait* instance here. Next we have to implement the [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48989049/selenium-how-selenium-identifies-elements-visible-or-not-is-is-possible-that-i/48990165#48990165) instance i.e. *wait1* / *wait2* within your code through proper [ExpectedConditions](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html) clauses.

Comment: Thank you so much for explain this. However, I have to catch the exception to know whether the element was not found.

Comment: Sure. See we have just defined the `WebDriverWait` instance here. Next we have to implement it within our code through `ExpectedCondition` clauses. See the [**`ExpectedCondition`**](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedCondition.html) documentation here.

Comment: Got it. :) My answer is below. :D Thank you! Learned something too. Your answer is more worthy than it. :) Other readers might learn from it too.

Answer (score 3):

Here it is:

```
public boolean waitForElementBoolean(WebDriver driver, By object){
    try {
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,60);
        wait.pollingEvery(2, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy(object));
        return true;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage()); 
        return false;
    }
}
```

I integrated the fluent wait with the explicit wait. :D Thank you guys! :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `WebDriverWait` with `polling` and `ignoring`

Example:

```
public boolean isElementPresentWithWait(WebDriver driver, WebElement element) {
    try {
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
        wait.pollingEvery(3, TimeUnit.SECONDS).ignoring(NoSuchElementException.class).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(element);
        return true;
    } catch (TimeoutException e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Methods `ignoring` and `pollingEvery` return instance of `FluentWait<WebDriver>`

Comment: The thing is that, I need to handle the exception. So ignoring it won't help. :|

Comment: You can handle it through `if(isElementPresentWithWait(element)) {} else {}` :)

Comment: is this different if it is separated? `wait.pollingEvery(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
   wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy(object));`

Comment: No. It works the same way. It's called `method chaining`.

You can even make 1 line of code with following `new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).pollingEvery(3,TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    .ignoring(NoSuchElementException.class)
    .until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(element);`

Answer (score 1):

you can try with this below code snippet

```
    /*
 * wait until expected element is visible
 */
public boolean waitForElement(WebDriver driver, By expectedElement) {
    boolean isFound = true;
    try {
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, timeoutInSeconds , 300);
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(expectedElement));
        makeWait(1);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        //System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        isFound = false;
    }
    return isFound;
}
```

Comment: That's Explicit Wait. Hmmmn. Is there a way to use fluent wait in boolean method?

Comment: Please see the comment of  @DebanjanB.

Comment: Can I use WebDriver wait with polling?

Comment: For reference you can follow this http://toolsqa.com/selenium-webdriver/implicit-explicit-n-fluent-wait/ .

Comment: @MielYan Yes you can

Comment: You can set the polling? How? @RafałLaskowski

Comment: @MielYan Check out my answer

Comment: For reference https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/12866/how-fluentwait-is-different-from-webdriverwait