# Selenium: How selenium identifies elements visible or not? Is is possible that it is loaded in DOM but not rendered on UI?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, dom, webdriverwait, expected-condition

1. Selenium: How selenium identifies elements visible or not? Is is possible that it is loaded in DOM but not rendered on UI? 
   I would like to verify a scenario where element is clickable, I know web drive has method "ElementToBeClickable" however, I would like to know the inner working. Please help me on this.
2. Also,how to handle a scenario where the element is loaded in the DOM but UI shows loading in progress, how to wait for complete load?
3. Please let me know, if the UI is not loaded then will selenium directly call the DOM element or if UI element is being loaded then it will fail the execution? I would really appreciate more technical explanation on this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- *Selenium* can identify the *presence* or *visibility* of the elements as soon as they are *present* or *visible* in the [*HTML DOM*](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom.asp). From user perspective you can invoke [`isDisplayed()`](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebElement.html#isDisplayed--) method on an [*WebElement*](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebElement.html) to examine if the intended *WebElement* is *displayed* or not. As per current implementation *Selenium* may not be distinguishing between *loaded* and *rendered* elements. The [*ElementToBeClickable*](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html#elementToBeClickable-org.openqa.selenium.WebElement-) method in [*ExpectedConditions*](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html) class sets an expectation for checking if an element is *visible* and *enabled* so that you can *click* it.
- When the *element is loaded in the DOM but UI shows loading in progress* you still have to **wait** for the *JavaScript* and *AJAX Calls* to complete loading the page so all the *WebElements* on the page becomes **interactable**. At most *to wait for complete load* you can  set the `pageLoadStrategy` to **normal** but may still have to induce [*WebDriverWait*](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/WebDriverWait.html) for the intended *WebElement* to become *present*, *visible*, *interactable* or *clickable*.

Here you can find a detailed discussion on [*Page load strategy*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43734797/page-load-strategy-for-chrome-driver/43737358#43737358)

- Of-coarse *if the UI is not loaded* *Selenium* may not be able to interact with a few of the DOM elements.

---

### Update

As per your counter question here are the different stages of an *WebElement* and the respective *ExpectedConditions* to check the stages :

- [**Presence** of an element](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html#presenceOfElementLocated-org.openqa.selenium.By-) :

  ```
   presenceOfElementLocated(By locator)
   An expectation for checking that an element is present on the DOM of a page. This does not necessarily mean that the element is visible.
  ```
- [**Visibility** of an element](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html#visibilityOf-org.openqa.selenium.WebElement-) :

  ```
   visibilityOf(WebElement element)
   An expectation for checking that an element, known to be present on the DOM of a page, is visible. Visibility means that the element is not only displayed but also has a height and width that is greater than 0.
  ```
- [Element to be **Clickable**](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html#elementToBeClickable-org.openqa.selenium.By-) :

  ```
   elementToBeClickable(By locator)
   An expectation for checking an element is visible and enabled such that you can click it.
  ```

> **Note** : As per the docs [**Element is Clickable - it is Displayed and Enabled**](https://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp#expected-conditions).

Comment: Thanks for quick reply, Please allow me to ask follow-up query, about ElementToBeClickable, I have gone through the official docs and stiil confused with the statement "An expectation for checking an element is visible and enabled such that you can click it." does this mean it will click only when it is visible on the UI or it has something to do with DOM again, I know the literal meaning but still would like to be sure about. Please help

Comment: Thanks. Please bear with me and allow me to ask follow-up queries, 1) for visibility of an element and Element to be Clickable, both are partially related to DOM, when it say's "element displayed but also has a height and width that is greater than 0" does this mean it is checking the UI element is actually displayed or based on downloaded css it determines that element is displayed. The only point I am trying to ensure that 2.) Is there any way to assert that element is actually displayed on the web page or just based on DOM and loaded css, html  selenium is performing actions?

Comment: `presence`, `visibility(displayed)` and `interactability(clickability)` all are related to different states of an _WebElement_ with in the _HTML DOM_. The states are distinct. Use the appropriate _ExpectedConditions_ as per your requirement.

Comment: Thanks a lot for clarification